# Unable to set up apache cxf properly in eclipse

Tags: cxf

I use eclipse Helios Service Release 2 version for apache cxf. When I go to windo->preferences->Web services-> CXF 2.x preferences, and set up the cxf runtime, then the version and type doesn't get filled up automatically, which happens on any other system I have tried, What can be the problem? This is why, when I try to create a web service, it shows me "Java virtual machine error" - Could not find the main class, Program is exiting error.

Plz help me what to do to set up apache cxf properly in eclipse helios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to incompatibility of jaxb version present inside java and apache cxf. I update my java runtime to contain the latest version of jaxb (same in apache cxf and java runtime). It worked fine then.